# Select a date range

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following MySQL statement that I am trying to use to select a week's worth of data from a table in my database (I will need to add at least one additional condition after I figure this part out). I run this query and it seems to execute properly, but returns no results. I know that there is at least one record on `2013-12-16` from a different query

```sql
SET @beginDate := '2013-12-16';
SET @period := 7;
SET @endDate := DATE_ADD(@beginDate, INTERVAL @period DAY);
SET @company := 'companyname';

SELECT offercode, firstname, lastname, address1, address2, city, state, zipcode, phone, dealer, expdate, company
FROM dialerview
WHERE company = @company AND expdate >= @begin_date AND expdate <= @end_date;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured out that in fixing a different problem I introduced a new one. The issue was that I did not use the same variable names in the `SET` statements and in the `SELECT` query.

Now I feel stupid :/